# Need to pivot data based on their values into coresponding columns in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have 3 tables with a one-to-many relationship. 
let say orders and order items. Items have product codes like a, b, c, d, etc...

There are about 15 different product codes in the system.

When joined I need to pivot the data to have orders and product codes as in the same row and just covert product code into boolean flag as 1 or 0.

I know I can use self join 15 times or use a lookup in SELECT like this

`IIF((select DISTINCT 1 from <product code table> where code = 'a' and <join from order item table>) is null, 0, 1)` for each product code.

Performance is not so good by doing this. So I'm wondering if there a better way to either use PIVOT, CROSS APPLY or something else.

Query tried and it works but hopping there is a better way to do this.

```
SELECT 
    order_id,
    order_item_id,
    IIF((select DISTINCT 1 from product_codes c where code = 'a' and i.item_product_code_id = c.product_code_id) is null, 0, 1) as a,
    IIF((select DISTINCT 1 from product_codes c where code = 'b' and i.item_product_code_id = c.product_code_id) is null, 0, 1) as b,
    IIF((select DISTINCT 1 from product_codes c where code = 'c' and i.item_product_code_id = c.product_code_id) is null, 0, 1) as c,
    IIF((select DISTINCT 1 from product_codes c where code = 'd' and i.item_product_code_id = c.product_code_id) is null, 0, 1) as d,
    IIF((select DISTINCT 1 from product_codes c where code = 'f' and i.item_product_code_id = c.product_code_id) is null, 0, 1) as e,
    IIF((select DISTINCT 1 from product_codes c where code = 'g' and i.item_product_code_id = c.product_code_id) is null, 0, 1) as f,
    IIF((select DISTINCT 1 from product_codes c where code = 'h' and i.item_product_code_id = c.product_code_id) is null, 0, 1) as g,
FROM orders o INNER JOIN order_items i ON o.order_id = i.order_id
```

Here is the sample. On the left is what the query result looks like and on the right is the desired result.( I can't ppost images inside yet)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jmQy.jpg

Comment: we would need a little bit more than this. I would like to see sample data and desired output

Comment: Add sample data and your expected result and show us what have u been tried

Comment: I added the screenshot for more understanding.

Comment: @DougCoats any more question I can do?